# How to get the value of the element in ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, element, watir

Can some one please let me know how to extract the value present in the field id='2' so that I can use the same value in another text field.

So what exactly I want is to get only the value 525XXXXXXX01166 from the below tag which i need to pass on to other text field to continue the test. but in source nothing else is present. I have also attached the source.

field id="2" value="525xxxxxx01166"

Below is the complete source

response got
field id="0" value="0110"
field id="2" value="525XXXXXXXXX66"
field id="3" value="000000"
field id="4" value="000000010000"
field id="6" value="000000010000"
field id="7" value="0831112100"
field id="11" value="000213"
field id="32" value="550060"
field id="33" value="012295"
field id="37" value="123453389112"
field id="38" value="103063"
field id="39" value="00"
field id="41" value="3333489"
field id="48" value="F2001S92032844233333212"
field id="49" value="784"
field id="51" value="784"
field id="63" value="SUasdsdGPLA"
Response - Success
<-- 0110 000224 33433489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
text = 'response got field id="0" value="525XXXXXXXXX66"'
matcher = text.match(/value="(.+)"/)
puts matcher.captures.first
```

Gives you this result:

```
525XXXXXXXXX66
```

Sadly this regular expression won't work well if you want to extract all values from a multi-line string. It would have to be modified further for such a purpose. However, for the scenario you described, it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the text in a variable called 't':

```
row = t.split("\n").detect {|v| v =~ /id\=\"2\"/}
/value\=\"(?<value>[\dX]+)/.match(row)[:value]
```

Will return:

```
"525XXXXXXXXX66"
```

Comment: When I try this , I get message as undefined local variable or method 't' for main:object (name error)

Comment: He did say "Assuming you have the text in a variable called 't'", you know. Means you must change it to the name of your variable in your code.

Comment: Hi... I am new this and not able to figure out the above solution. In the below line... can you please tell what will be 't'. I tried few stuff but unable to make out ....

field id="2" value="525XXXXXXXXX66"